# c# qr barcode reading (unicode)

Tags: c#, .net, console, qr-code, ironbarcode

I'm trying to create a QR barcode in .NET using [IronBarcode](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/).
I'm following their tutorial for writing binary data, but it isn't working working with Arabic text for some reason. It works great with any English that I input, but with Arabic the console output is `?????`. I've tried UTF8, UTF7 but nothing seems to be  working.

**Tutorial:**
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/tutorials/csharp-qr-code-generator/#reading-and-writing-binary-data

My code is:

```
using IronBarCode;

var Msg = "مرحبا";

byte[] BinaryData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Msg);
var bitmap = IronBarCode.QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(BinaryData,500, IronBarCode.QRCodeWriter.QrErrorCorrectionLevel.Highest).ToBitmap();

var barcodeResult = IronBarCode.BarcodeReader.ReadASingleBarcode(bitmap);
var stringResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(barcodeResult.BinaryValue);
 
Console.WriteLine(stringResult) // outputs '?????'
```

Please can someone advise what I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps UTF7 -> UTF8?

Comment: Technically i believe strings in .NET are UTF16 by default- so System.Text.Encoding.Unicode would be a better bet than UTF8 or UTF7 which could cause transcoding issues

Comment: For users who do not have nuget access, this can be downloaded as a zip aswell:
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/downloads/csharp-qr-code-reader.zip

Answer (score 3):

```
var Msg = "هذا لا يعمل";
byte[] BinaryData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Msg);
var bitmap = IronBarCode.QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(BinaryData, 500, IronBarCode.QRCodeWriter.QrErrorCorrectionLevel.Highest).ToBitmap();

var barcodeResult = IronBarCode.BarcodeReader.ReadASingleBarcode(bitmap);
var stringResult = 
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(barcodeResult.BinaryValue);
// stringResult is "هذا لا يعمل"
```

The issue you are seeing is that Console.WriteLine doesn’t support Arabic characters in Visual Studio. It prints "?????" for all non-Roman characters.

You can verify the correct result by saving to file, or putting in a debugging breakpoint and hover over the variable in Visual Studio.

This video explains the issue, and also has a work-around:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rTqBnJ8HrSc

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

Comment: link to MDSN docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=net-5.0